# How to remove duplicate data using mysql from a table

Tags: mysql

This is my table like result. i want to delete all duplicate data from rows. how can i do it using mysql[image]?

Comment: This answers your question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3312066/4132369

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove duplicate rows in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3311903/remove-duplicate-rows-in-mysql)

Comment: **Please provide the query that created that result.** ADD it into the question i.e. [edit it](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/47123801/edit) (do not use a comment for this)

Comment: Observation: The author states *"table like result"* and whilst there is mention of "delete" it it equally possible that all that is needed is **SELECT DISTINCT**